# How to import/include plugin in testing with Jest / Vue-test-utils?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

When testing a base button implementation using Jest and Vue-test-utils, the tests work but I am getting the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: b-button - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I am confident is because I am not including the `Buefy` plugin dependencies correctly, and I don't have a lot of experience here.
Here is my single file component for the base button:

```
<template>
  <b-button data-testid="base-button" @click="$emit('click')">
    {{ buttonLabel }}
  </b-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    buttonLabel: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Button',
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

And here is my testing:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import BaseButton from '@/components/base/BaseButton'

const Component = BaseButton
const ComponentName = 'BaseButton'

const global_wrapper = mount(Component, {})

describe(ComponentName, () => {
  it('should render the button', () => {
    const wrapper = global_wrapper
    const button = wrapper.find('[data-testid="base-button"]')
    expect(button.exists()).toBeTruthy()
  }),
    it('should emit the click event on a click', async () => {
      const wrapper = global_wrapper
      console.log(wrapper.html())
      const button = wrapper.find('[data-testid="base-button"]')
      button.trigger('click')

      const clickCalls = wrapper.emitted('click')

      expect(clickCalls).toHaveLength(1)
    })
})
```

I would appreciate help understanding the appropriate way to include the Buefy `b-button` component in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the Buefy plugin (or any other plugin), you can use something like `const localVue = createLocalVue()` from vue-test-utils to create a local vue and use the Buefy plugin, `localVue.use(Buefy)` as below. This `localVue` can be included when mounting the wrapper.

```
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '../Component'
import Buefy from 'buefy'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Buefy)

const global_wrapper = mount(Component, {
  localVue,
})
```

If you only have one or two components you want to use from the plugin, you can import the individual components and run `localVue.use` multiple times as such:

```
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '../Component'
import { Button, Checkbox } from 'buefy'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Button)
localVue.use(Checkbox)

const global_wrapper = mount(Component, {
  localVue,
})
```

Comment: Note: `createLocalVue`  was removed in version 2 of `@vue/test-utils`

Answer (score 3):

Posting for a Vue 3 solution. As [StevenSiebert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13129353/stevensiebert) mentioned, `createLocalVue` is no longer available with v2 `@vue/test-utils` (needed for Vue 3 tests). You'll need to use the `global` object in your tests.

Per the [docs](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global) for `mount`, to register the plugin for one-off mounts, you can use:

```
import foo from 'foo'

mount(Component, {
  global: {
    plugins: [foo]
  }
})
```

To register the plugin in all tests, you can add to your test setup file, i.e. `setup.js`. See [docs](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#config-global)

```js
import foo from 'foo'

config.global.plugins = [foo]
```